# How to correctly use AVG() in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I track base station performance in an RF network by storing SSI values in this table:

```
TABLE BASE_SSI:
    wayside     BIGINT (PK)
    timestamp   datetime
    base        varchar(12)
    ssi         int
```

SSI is read once per hour and stored in this table with about one years' worth of readings.

I can extract one days' worth of SSI values for any given day in the past with this query:

```
select wayside,timestamp,base,ssi from BASE_SSI 
where wayside=225520220000 
and timestamp > DATEADD(day,-7,getdate())
and timestamp < DATEADD(day,-6,getdate())
order by timestamp desc
```

which gives me these results:

```
wayside         timestamp             base        ssi
225520220000    2018-11-02 00:21:09   423.3.01    33
225520220000    2018-11-01 22:31:03   423.3.01    32
225520220000    2018-11-01 20:40:53   423.3.01    32
225520220000    2018-11-01 18:50:45   423.3.01    31
225520220000    2018-11-01 17:00:35   423.3.01    33
225520220000    2018-11-01 15:10:26   423.3.01    34
225520220000    2018-11-01 13:20:20   423.3.01    38
225520220000    2018-11-01 11:30:11   423.3.01    37
225520220000    2018-11-01 09:40:03   423.3.01    35
225520220000    2018-11-01 07:49:03   423.3.01    35
225520220000    2018-11-01 05:59:50   423.3.01    34
225520220000    2018-11-01 04:09:43   423.3.01    34
225520220000    2018-11-01 02:19:34   423.3.01    34
```

What I need is a query that gives me the AVERAGE ssi for this 24-hour period in the past, for all waysides. The results should be:

```
wayside         date         base        avg_ssi
225520220000    2018-11-01   423.3.01    34
225520230000    2018-11-01   423.2.21    21
225520240000    2018-11-01   423.4.11    18
225520250000    2018-11-01   423.1.21    55
225520260000    2018-11-01   422.2.01    62
225520270000    2018-11-01   452.3.07    33
225520280000    2018-11-01   425.1.03    25
```

I only need integral values for average ssi, as shown.

I've tried using AVG(ssi) in a SELECT statement, but I am not sure how to apply this to all wayside values in a selected time period. For example, in the original query,
I add 'AVG(ssi) as avg_ssi' in the SELECT line but it only yields the 'average' SSI for each single record, which is the same as the SSI value.

My pseudo-SQL version of this query would be 'display the 24-hour average SSI of every wayside for a given date'.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `avg` with `group by` on `CONVERT(char(10), timestamp,126)` let datetime to `yyyy-MM-dd` format `group by` each date.

```
select wayside,CONVERT(char(10), timestamp,126),base,avg(ssi) as avg_ssi
from BASE_SSI 
where timestamp > DATEADD(day,-7,getdate()) and timestamp < DATEADD(day,-6,getdate())
group by CONVERT(char(10), timestamp,126),base,wayside
order by timestamp desc
```

**EDIT**

From your comment you can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to get the first `ssi` by each `base`.

```
SELECT wayside,
       CONVERT(char(10), timestamp,126),
       base,
       ssi as avg_ssi 
FROM (
    select wayside,timestamp,base,ssi,Row_number() over(partition by base order by timestamp) rn
    from BASE_SSI 
    where timestamp > DATEADD(day,-7,getdate()) and timestamp < DATEADD(day,-6,getdate())
) t1
where rn = 1
order by timestamp desc
```

Comment: Here the 'avg_ssi' column returns the FIRST ssi value of the group, not the average of all 14 ssi values in the sample. In other words, the ssi is 26 instead of 24, which is the hand-calculated average.

Comment: @user3235770 Could you provide some sample data from `BASE_SSI` table?

Comment: Because I only saw  `base = 423.3.01` in your sample data

Comment: @user3235770 If I understand correctly you can try my edit answer

Comment: First, I made a mistake in the table schema: the wayside column has no primary key, so there can be many entries for the same wayside. 

To check these queries I created this table from scratch with just two rows:

    wayside         timestamp             base        ssi
    225520220000    2018-11-02 00:21:09   423.3.01    15
    225520220000    2018-11-01 22:31:03   423.3.01    45

Comment: (had to split this comment into two)If I run your first query against this table, the result is:

    wayside         timestamp             base        avg_ssi
    225520220000    2018-11-02 00:21:09   423.3.01    15

This is the result set from the second query:

    wayside         (no column name)      base        avg_ssi
    225520220000    2018-11-02 00:21:09   423.3.01    15


In neither case did the avg_ssi column contain the average, which should be 30.